# ionic serve starts on localhost and not the server IP

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When running ionic serve I see this:

```
  Gulp startup tasks: [ 'sass', 'watch' ]
  Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
  Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
  Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
  Ionic server commands, enter:
    restart or r to restart the client app from the root
    goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
    consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
    serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
    quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
```

Which means I cannot access the app from a browser as its only listening for localhost. How can I change localhost to the actual server IP?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ionic address` gives a list of addresses. Select one of them. E.g.:

```
Multiple addresses available.
Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:
 1) 10.0.0.9 (wlan0)
 2) 172.16.58.1 (vmnet1)
 3) 172.16.16.1 (vmnet8)
 4) localhost
Std in before prompt
Address Selection:
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have no idea how I missed that :)

Comment: Woah, I get no output from `ionic address` so I used `ionic serve -address xx.xx.xx.xx` (127.0.0.1 / localhost is what I wanted)

Answer (score 7):

**NEW ANSWER:**

**For the newer version of ionic this has been changed to `--address`**

- `ionic address` command give the option to select your IP address. And you can select one from.
- You can explicitely define IP address and port like this:

  `ionic serve --address address --port port //8100 is default`

  example 1: `ionic serve --address localhost  --port 8101`

  example 2: `ionic serve --address localhost  --port 8101`
- try --lab option to see multiple platforms at once.

  `ionic serve --address localhost --lab`

Clikc to [Learn more options](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/)

OLd Answer:

Use `-address localhost`

run

```
ionic serve -address localhost
```

to test your apps on multiple screen sizes and platform types use with --lab

```
ionic serve --lab -address localhost
```

Comment: I am trying this but no luck. I guess Ionic has changed this command to something else.

Comment: @Tanzeel Thanks for pointing this, It has been updaed in newer version, I have just updaed the answer accordingly, hope this will help. Thanks.