# Firebase: This domain is not authorized

Tags: firebase, mobile, oauth

I imported [Firebase JS v3 API](https://firebase.google.com) and used to initialize Firebase using:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

However the app failed to load correctly via web browser on localhost, resulting in the following error:

> Error: This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your
>   Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the
>   Firebase console.
>
> firebase.js:71:1333

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the `localhost` domain to `OAuth redirect domains` (within `SETUP SIGN IN METHOD` on the `Auth` tab of Firebase console).

**Updated: Aug 14 2023** -
Now the `Authorized domains` section is moved to `settings` on the `Authentication` tab of Firebase console.

Comment: Ohhh they moved this setting into the "Sign in method" subsection of the "Auth" section. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work instantly? I am using a fake local domain set up in my hosts file like myapp.localdevmachine.com. I added it with and without the subdomain part to the firebase console in the OAuth redirect domains but I still get the Unauthorized Request Origin error in the popup. It doesn't matter which provider I use they all come back to that error. I set it up about 1 hour ago and it still fails. I have also localhost, and 127.0.0.1 added to the domains.

Comment: @JavierLerones If have you made **all the required steps** (https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) for upgrading to the new Google API, then yes it should work.

Comment: what means "using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 inside a different web browser"? how it relates to ionic app configuration?

Comment: @ciekawy I think it was a connecting issue to port 8100. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029532/ionic-serve-starts-on-localhost-and-not-the-server-ip.

Comment: Ah so it's not about real device... I've never experienced the problem locally and thought your issue was concerning device/simulator

Comment: you can add 127.0.0.1 to authorized domains  -  box shows red invalidated but it will still allow you to add it in the add domain section of firebase authentication

Comment: my website was live so i didnt had localhost, it worked by copying all the websites from firebase auth authorized domains to google cloud platform - api and services - credentials - browser key - website restriction filter

Answer (score 65):

> **in firebase console Auth --> Authorised domains**

[image]

---

> **must equal (in Google cloud console -- > API & Services --> credentials ) :**

[image]

---

> **must equal (in api config) :**

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Solution which worked for me after trying out all the options on the listed above and on other sites regarding using FireBase oAuth was the following:

1. login at https://console.cloud.google.com
2. Go to APIs & Services > Credentials

[image]

Once here, locate API Key you are using in your app that connects to FireBase

1. Now add your custom domain to HTTP Referrers

[image]

[image]

For android or ios or having your application on all three mediums, you will need to create API keys per medium.

Comment: Additional fixes for some here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1444, it appears that for each domain added to FireBase Security Auth Section must also manually get added to Google Console APIs and Services

Comment: My man! Thanks so much. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure the "authDomain" in your config matches the one in your firebase console. If you're running the app on localhost, make sure it's set to localhost and localhost exists on your firebase console.

Auth -> Sign In Method -> OAuth redirect domains

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...", // this should match the one on your firebase console
    databaseURL: "...",
    storageBucket: "",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Mine matches, yet I still get the error: Uncaught Error: An internal error has occurred.

Comment: I traced down the error message down to the point that, my api key expired was the culprit. I have no idea why it expired. But got it resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Firebase now has localhost as Authorized domains by default but if you are facing this for a custom domain, here is a quick solution.

- Go to Google console Authentication tab > Settings > Authorized domains
- Add your domain

[image]

(PS - About version, I'm using Firebase 9.9.3 on React.)

Answer (score 6):

**Firebase Users**

For me the source of the error was that the domain was not added in the firebase console.
Here is an image in the firebase console to add the custom domain for your website:
[image: firebase console]

Comment: how to add localhost:3000 to auth domain

Comment: @skyshine Click add domain and type `localhost` without port number if it's not already in the list. :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Problem Authorised domain Firebase Locahost OAUTH2

If you are using Google Chrome you can see a problem with the Identity Toolkit API
 DISABLE. You need to enabled this API on the google cloud project to get OAUTH servcies in Firebase project.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=project-id

Answer (score 1):

Not really specific to Android, but check the address in your `actionCodeSettings`.

`actionCodeSettings.url` must be correct and whitelisted.

[Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link in JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address)

Answer (score 1):

For those having this issue in Heroku:

Make sure you keep the **authDomain** property with the same value you got from Firebase.

DO NOT change this to the current Heroku domain.

Comment: would you please explain or give an example.  I’m facing the same problem with Heroku .

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me, as I already had localhost in Authorized domains list. For me the problem was incorrect API key, I must have somehow deleted one of the characters from it. I got a more descriptive (or rather - not misleading) error message when I changed to `signInWithPopup` to `signInWithRedirect`. Possibly the same problem might happen when the API key is expired.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me but this did.

1. Go to Google console **Authentication** tab > **Sign In Method** > **Authorized Domains**
2. Add `127.0.0.1`

localhost was already in my Authorized Domains but in my case I needed to add `127.0.0.1` as well

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

The important point is.. you must add the yourprojectid.firebaseapp.com domain to the authorized domains.. not your real domain name. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem also and the domain was like this:
127.0.0.1:5173/
I just turned it into: localhost:5173 and it ran
without a problem.