# Custom authDomain in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase's built-in oAuth feature for an SPA.

This SPA is on a domain of it's own, say `foobar.com`

The problem is, when the oauth popup is opened, the old `foobar.firebaseapp.com` domain is used, instead of the new `foobar.com` domain

My init looks like this

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: 'foobar.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://foobar.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'foobar.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '123456'
})
```

I am guessing `authDomain` may have something to do with it, but if I change it to `foobar.com` I get the error:

```
 code: "auth/popup-closed-by-user", message: "The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation."}
```

In short, is there a way I am missing to customize the oAuth url for Firebase?

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344066/firebase-this-domain-is-not-authorized/48475438#48475438

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I saw a lot of answers in [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11485271/1145905) that pointed to the need to set up custom domains authorization, checking HTTP/S URI schemes, etc (I had followed most of them, including making sure my custom domain was authorized under Firebase Hosting, Firebase Authentication and even on the GCP Identity Platform "Authorized Domains" settings ([https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity/settings?project=\](https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity/settings?project=%5C)<your-gcp-project-id>). That is, none of the linked answers seemed to be specific to Firebase Auth so here is my experience, FWIW:

The following `Authorisation Error` message was showing up on the "Sign in with Google" popup:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://<project-id>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}
```

After a lot of digging, I realized I needed to set the value of "Authorized redirect URIs" to `https://<my-auth-subdomain>.mydomain.org/__/auth/handler`, referencing my custom domain. See the below attachments.

[image: OAuth Client ID settings]
[image: Google APIs Credentials settings]

It wasn't immediately obvious to me, but I also had to make the above settings on the OAuth 2.0 Client ID that was auto generated by Google Service. Following this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34462390/1145905), I had initially created a new client ID that didn't end up making any difference.

Comment: You saved me so much time!

Comment: Hey, I've gone through these steps (though I didn't have a "Web client" entry in the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs list), making sure my authDomain value matches one of the URIs I have listed in Authorized Redirect URIs, and it's been days now since I did this (far beyond the mins to hours it says it should take).  I'm still getting the permissions error.  Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidMarkowitz I'm not sure why the "Web client" row would be missing for you cos it's typically auto-created by Google. Perhaps follow up with the GCP support team to see if something changed?

Comment: Ok. At what point did the Web client get created?  Right after you added your client IDs?  I also noticed you have API keys auto generated by firebase, something else I don't have.  Did you do something in firebase to generate those?

Comment: I'm not sure when the web client got created, it must've been when the web app was generated (mine was created from the Firebase console)

Comment: Any idea how this could work on localhost? It appears to be impossible to set `authDomain` to `localhost:8080` - setting any port will crash Firebase..

Answer (score 17):

The `authDomain` relies on specific scripts being available on that domain. If your Single-Page App is hosted on Firebase Hosting with a custom domain, you will be able to use that domain as the `authDomain`.

Alternatively, you could set up a custom domain for Firebase Hosting on a subdomain of your domain e.g. `auth.foobar.com` and you'd then be able to use `auth.foobar.com` as your `authDomain`.

There is currently no support for using a non-Firebase-Hosting domain as your `authDomain`.

Comment: Hi Michael, My custom domain is on firebase hosting, but it still has this issue. Is there some way I could debug further?

Comment: I'd suggest [reaching out to support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to get some specific debugging help for your particular site.

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344066/firebase-this-domain-is-not-authorized/48475438#48475438

Comment: That is not the case, I was able to use an `authDomain` hosted by another provider perfectly fine. See the answer by @kip2 below

Comment: @michael-bleigh which specific scripts should be available on authDomain

Comment: Hi @MichaelBleigh, I was wondering about this same exact question and this is the only place I found so far that mentioned this. Is "There is currently no support for using a non-Firebase-Hosting domain as your authDomain" still applicable ? I feel like it is, but I had trouble finding confirmation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Authentication --> Sign-in Method, you will put you custom domian under Authorized domains section