# Ionic App: Firebase Authenticate with using OAuth Provider shows AUTH_DOMAIN instead of Custom Domain

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I implemented a Login with Google API following the Firebase Authentication docs (***Authenticate Using OAuth Providers with Cordova***) [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova).  However, it shows the Project Default AUTH_DOMAIN. How do I change it to show custom URL?

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="example.page.link" scheme="https" />
    <host name="example-app.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity were you able to successfully parse data with universal-links back to the app? I can't seem to authenticate users on Android, the auth object isn't sent back after the redirect for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your domain when [adding Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) to your app?

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Also, using your own domain is not as easy as it sounds. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856179/custom-authdomain-in-firebase) for more info.