# Google Authentication w/Firebase blocked even after updating authorized domains

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am currently setting up the Google Auth provider within my firebase application.  I have enabled the Google Auth provider, as well as the authorized domains within the authentication tab.

[image]

[image]

Even after updating my authorized domains, etc. I am still receiving the following error:

iframe.js:299 Info: The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (ys-provider-map.firebaseapp.com) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

Is there something I may have missed, etc. Any and all feedback is much appreciated

Comment: That appears to be correct if `ys-provider-map` is indeed your Project ID. Does your `firebaseConfig` object include an `authDomain` that matches `ys-provider-map.firebaseapp.com`?

Comment: Yes, so everything should be working properly.  Any idea why it wouldn't be?

Comment: I have added a comment below did you managed to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue was reported in this [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/998) thread.

The reason for this error may be because you didn't have the firebase app domain itself (*.firebaseapp.com) included in the Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) list in the Google API credentials for the app key (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key).

This must be a fairly recent requirement as accepting requests from the actual site domain was enough beforehand.

Hope above information helps.

Comment: I have seen this, but am unsure of where exactly I need to add the *.firebaseapp.com, could you by chance include a screenshot of where this needs to be added or something along those lines

Comment: @Rob Terrell please check this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54156586/18265638) explained clearly with screenshots